# Hibernate ddl-auto=update, how to intercept errors

Tags: java, hibernate

Using ddl-auto=update, hibernate properly updates the schema based on the java Entities.
In case there is an error, for example it tries to create a not null column on a table that is not empty, it does not raise an exception and silently continue the execution.

Our need is that hibernate immediately throws an exception in case there is any error during schema update.
Is there any option to enable this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Hibernate would only update your specfic table if you have coded it to do so in your model. This is not an unexpected behaviour since hibernate was told to create a not null column as defined in the model. However if you still want to see table and column creations , you can enable the property from here : https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/show-hibernate-sql-query-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Hi, thanks fo the reply.  I agree, the point was not that. We need that hibernate, in case of an error occours executing an SQL statement (e.g. a column not null with some data in the table), raise the exception that the database throws. At the moment, instead, it sinlently continue the set of operations, and we have no feedback about the error. We'd rather that the exception would stop the startup of our application, in order to immediately fix it in test environment.

Comment: Found!  hibernate.hbm2ddl.halt_on_error   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found: hibernate.hbm2ddl.halt_on_error